# Can I share with the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to share with it?

I know I can post, but I would like to share what has been already shared before.

I saw on other questions that people are asking what is the difference among post and share. 
Please don't comment asking this again here :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was possible.

Firstly, you have to know the original object id, let's say someone share a photo(id 536015993184436), you must retrieve the original photo id, i.e. 536015993184436, not the post_id, e.g. https://www.facebook.com/USER_ID/posts/POST_ID.

Then you have to combine the photo id with https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid= and become **https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=536015993184436** to share.

[image]

Shared the photo successfully:

[image]

The only drawback was, the share wouldn't increase the share count shown in the post.

[image]

For other type of post, e.g. status, you have to share the link on https://www.facebook.com/USER_ID/posts/POST_ID form.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is all wonderful. Thank you very much for the illustrated guide!

Answer (score 0):

well you cant share post using graph api yet! there no graph api which allows users to Share. you can post but you cant share it